# How to make zoomable sunburst to zoom on click to show children?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement a d3v6 zoomable sunburst based on https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst in Angular. But due to some reason the transitions and translation are not working on click. Since I'm new to d3 js I'm not able to figure it out. Any help would be highly appreciated thanks.

Here's the error stack

> Error:  attribute transform: Expected number, "rotate(NaN) translate(N…".

Here's the code i am working on

```
const width = 632;
const height = 500;
let parent;
let root;
let g;
let path;
let label;
let arc;
let svg;

const format = d3.format(',d');
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.quantize(d3.interpolateRainbow, data.children.length + 1));
const radius = width / 6;

arc =  d3.arc()
    .startAngle(d => d.x0)
    .endAngle(d => d.x1)
    .padAngle(d => Math.min((d.x1 - d.x0) / 2, 0.005))
    .padRadius(radius * 1.5)
    .innerRadius(d => d.y0 * radius)
    .outerRadius(d => Math.max(d.y0 * radius, d.y1 * radius - 1));

root = partition(data);
root.each(d => d.current = d);
console.log(root);

svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
  .style('width', width)
  .style('height', height)
  .style('font', '10px sans-serif');

g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2},${width / 2})`);

path = g.append('g')
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
  // .enter().append('path')
  .join('path')
  .attr('fill', d => { while (d.depth > 1) {d = d.parent; } return color(d.data.name); })
  .attr('fill-opacity', d => arcVisible(d.current) ? (d.children ? 0.6 : 0.4) : 0)
  .attr('d', d => arc(d.current));

path.filter(d => d.children)
  .style('cursor', 'pointer')
  .on('click', clicked);

path.append('title')
  .text(d => `${d.ancestors().map(d => d.data.name).reverse().join('/')}\n${format(d.value)}`);

 label = g.append('g')
  .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .style('user-select', 'none')
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
  .join('text')
  .attr('dy', '0.35em')
  .attr('fill-opacity', d => +labelVisible(d.current))
  .attr('transform', d => labelTransform(d.current))
  .text(d => d.data.name);

parent = g.append('circle')
  .datum(root)
  .attr('r', radius)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
  .on('click', clicked);


function clicked(event, p) {
  parent.datum(p.parent || root);

  root.each(d => d.target = {
    x0: Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (d.x0 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0))) * 2 * Math.PI,
    x1: Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (d.x1 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0))) * 2 * Math.PI,
    y0: Math.max(0, d.y0 - p.depth),
    y1: Math.max(0, d.y1 - p.depth)
  });

  const t = g.transition().duration(750);

  // Transition the data on all arcs, even the ones that aren’t visible,
  // so that if this transition is interrupted, entering arcs will start
  // the next transition from the desired position.
  path.transition(t)
    .tween('data', d => {
      console.log(d);
      const i = d3.interpolate(d.current, d.target);
      return t => d.current = i(t);
    })
    .filter(function(d) {
      return +this.getAttribute('fill-opacity') || arcVisible(d.target);
    })
    .attr('fill-opacity', d => arcVisible(d.target) ? (d.children ? 0.6 : 0.4) : 0)
    .attrTween('d', d => () => arc(d.current));

  label.filter(function(d) {
    return +this.getAttribute('fill-opacity') || labelVisible(d.target);
  }).transition(t)
    .attr('fill-opacity', d => +labelVisible(d.target))
    .attrTween('transform', d => () => labelTransform(d.current));
}

function arcVisible(d) {
  return d.y1 <= 3 && d.y0 >= 1 && d.x1 > d.x0;
}

function labelVisible(d) {
  return d.y1 <= 3 && d.y0 >= 1 && (d.y1 - d.y0) * (d.x1 - d.x0) > 0.03;
}

function labelTransform(d) {
  const x = (d.x0 + d.x1) / 2 * 180 / Math.PI;
  const y = (d.y0 + d.y1) / 2 * radius;
  return `rotate(${x - 90}) translate(${y},0) rotate(${x < 180 ? 0 : 180})`;
}

function partition(data) {
    const root = d3.hierarchy(data)
      .sum(d => d.value)
      .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
    console.log(root);
    return d3.partition()
      .size([2 * Math.PI, root.height + 1])
      (root);
  }
```

Comment: This is a v6 sunburst, are you using d3v4 with it?

Comment: @AndrewReid yeah i am using d3v6

Comment: @AndrewReid thanks for suggestion it was a versioning issue , moving to newer version of d3 solves the issue